# Want to be able to have dropdown menus through a chrome extension using javascript, but I can't seems to make them work like they do in the .html

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have been trying for a while now. I have a popup.html file which contains the css and html, and a popup.js which contains the javascript since I know chrome does not like inline js. The popup windows work well on the .html file opened through a browser but I cannot get them to work in the chrome extension.

This is the popup.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
    <title>Document</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <style>
    
 /* Container holding the image and the text */
    #wrapper{
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
    }


.header{
margin-bottom:0;
height:10%; 
width:100%;
background-color:#343430;
}

.search_bar input[type="text"]{
position:absolute;  
top:27px;
left:30px;

background-color:white; 
color:grey;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    
    color: white;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.top-left {/*Degree Audit*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 105px;
}

.top-right {/*Course Selection*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 500px;
}

.bottom-left { /*Plan*/
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 70px;
}

.bottom-centered {/*Search*/
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 650px;
}

.bottom-right {/*Enroll*/
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 460px;
}



.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.dropbtnSearch {
    background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #000080);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
  border: solid #ffda7d 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  
   
    position:absolute;
    bottom:20px;
    left:65px;
}

.dropbtnPlan {
    

    background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #000080);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
  border: solid #ffda7d 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  bottom:20px;
    left:212px;
    position:absolute;
}
.dropbtnPlan:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropbtnSearch:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropbtnAudit:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropbtnSelection:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropbtnEnroll {
     background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #000080);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
  border: solid #ffda7d 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  bottom:30px;
   
    position:absolute;
    bottom:20px;
    left:370px;
}
.dropbtnEnroll:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #ffd736);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropbtnAudit {
    background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #000080);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 4px 16px 4px 16px;
  border: solid #ffda7d 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
 
    position:absolute;
    bottom:60px;
    left:135px;
}

.dropbtnSelection {
    background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #000080);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #000080);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 2px 30px 2px 30px;
  border: solid #ffda7d 2px;
  text-decoration: none;

   
    position:absolute;
    bottom:60px;
    left:255px;
}



.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-contentSearch {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

    background-image:url(searchTest.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

    min-width: 506px;
    min-height:537px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-contentPlan {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
   background-color: #00E5FF;
    min-width: 600px;
    min-height:600px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}


.dropdown-contentEnroll {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
   background-color: #00E5FF;
    min-width: 600px;
    min-height:600px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-contentAudit {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
   background-color: #00E5FF;
    min-width: 600px;
    min-height:600px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-contentSelection {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
   background-color: #00E5FF;
    min-width: 600px;
    min-height:600px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}



/*<div class="bottom-left">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Search</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Course Name</a>
    <a href="#about">Requirements</a>
    <a href="#contact">etc</a>
    </div>


<a href="https://www.google.com"><div class="bottom-left">Search</div></a>

 <a href="https://www.google.com"> <div class="top-left">Degree Audit</div></a>
 <a href="https://www.google.com">  <div class="top-right">Course Selection</div></a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com">  <div class="bottom-right">Enroll</div></a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com">  <div class="bottom-centered">Plan</div></a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com">  <div class="centered"></div></a>

    */


.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>




<div class="container">
<img src="kittyPathTesting.jpg" alt="kittyPath" width="500" height="181">






</div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="searchFunc()" class="dropbtnSearch">Search</button>
  <div id="myDropdownSearch" class="dropdown-contentSearch">

    <div class="header">
    <div class="search_bar">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter your search here">
</div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button id="testing" onclick="planFunc()" class="dropbtnPlan">Plan</button>

  <div id="myDropdownPlan" class="dropdown-contentPlan">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Sup</a><br>
    <img src="na.jpg" alt="Na">
    <a href="#about">More bullshit</a><br>
    <a href="#contact">Here click this to plan your schedule mofo</a><br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="enrollFunc()" class="dropbtnEnroll">Enroll</button>
  <div id="myDropdownEnroll" class="dropdown-contentEnroll">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Sup</a><br>
    <img src="na.jpg" alt="Na">
    <a href="#about">More bullshit</a><br>
    <a href="#contact">Here click this to plan your schedule mofo</a><br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="auditFunc()" class="dropbtnAudit">Degree Audit</button>
  <div id="myDropdownAudit" class="dropdown-contentAudit">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Sup</a><br>
    <img src="na.jpg" alt="Na">
    <a href="#about">More bullshit</a><br>
    <a href="#contact">Here click this to plan your schedule mofo</a><br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="selectionFunc()" class="dropbtnSelection">Course Selection</button>
  <div id="myDropdownSelection" class="dropdown-contentSelection">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Sup</a><br>
    <img src="na.jpg" alt="Na">
    <a href="#about">More bullshit</a><br>
    <a href="#contact">Here click this to plan your schedule mofo</a><br>
  </div>
</div>





<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

and the popup.js:

```js
// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
 
  if(!event.target.matches('.dropbtnPlan')) {
var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-contentPlan");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }

else  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtnSearch')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-contentSearch");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }

  if(!event.target.matches('.dropbtnEnroll')) {
var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-contentEnroll");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }

  if(!event.target.matches('.dropbtnAudit')) {
var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-contentAudit");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }

  if(!event.target.matches('.dropbtnSelection')) {
var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-contentSelection");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }

}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById(".dropdown-contentPlan button").addEventListener("click", planFunc);

    planFunc.preventDefault();
}      
);



function searchFunc() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdownSearch").classList.toggle("show");
}
function planFunc() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdownPlan").classList.toggle("show");
}

function enrollFunc() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdownEnroll").classList.toggle("show");
}

function auditFunc() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdownAudit").classList.toggle("show");
}



function selectionFunc() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdownSelection").classList.toggle("show");
}



function main() {
    var source = document.getElementById('myDropdownSelection').value;
    document.getElementById(".dropbtnSelection").innerHTML = source;
}
```

Comment: Not a solution to your problem but why have multiple functions that all do the same thing? `.classList.toggle("show");` Why not assign those elements with a `class` and have one function to deal with `.classList.toggle("show");` for all elements of that `class`?

Comment: Here is a quick [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/m13a1br7/) I have thrown together.

Comment: Honestly I'm pretty need to this it was just in case I wanted to add different functionality for each one but you are probably right lol

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying that is much more efficient. Thanks for helping! I'm gonna change that part of it at least

Comment: You are very welcome. I know it isn't fixing your current problem but that is the first thing I noticed while looking through the source code. Repeating source code can get messy to work with if it builds up too much so sometimes it's nice to make a few changes like that and keep things easier to work with. Also if you add more to that menu the `javascript` won't need updating/ a new function adding.

Comment: I appreciate your help thanks a lot. I am seeing more and more that it cannot be done, as in another GUI cannot just drop down. May have to find out how to open up another tab and insert my own html into it.